# Highcharts hiding series and keeping tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm working with Highcharts api.
I want to hide some series's curves but keep showing all values of all series on tooltip.

For example:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Cat',
    data: [[1, 15], [2, 18], [3, 10]]
}, {
    name: 'Dog',
    data: [[1, 12], [2, 18], [3, 11]]
}, {
    name: 'Rabbit',
    data: [[1, 12], [2, 22], [3, 9]]
}]
```

I want to hide Rabbit's curve and keep all values on tooltip.
If i point mouse on the first point (1) i have to see this values:
    Cat: 15
    Dog: 12
    Rabbit: 12

Comment: It is possible to use series.graph.hide() or series.group.hide() for hiding your series graph path: http://jsfiddle.net/ktjqbc7t/

Comment: That was exactly what i needed.

Comment: I am happy to hear that my example met your requirements. I am posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use series.graph.hide() or series.group.hide() for hiding series graph path:

```
 function(chart) {
  chart.series[2].update({
    marker: {
      enabled: false,
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    },

  })
  chart.series[2].group.hide();
}
```

Live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ktjqbc7t/

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `series.hide()` or `series.setVisible(false,false)` to hide the series. This would, in turn, remove the series from tooltip as well so you require a custom tooltip formatter to show the hidden series.
Example:

```
formatter: function () {
    var s = '';
    var series =  this.points[0].series.chart.series;
    var key = this.points[0].key;
    series.forEach((e,i) => {
        if(e){
            s += '<br/>' + e.name + ': ' +
            e.options.data[key] + 'm';
          }
        });
    return s;
}
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hcy6u4ya/